# How to compare multiple values and display error

Tags: javascript

Look this:

```
var a1 = 1;
var a2 = 2;
var a3 = 5;
var a4 = 2;
.
.
var a100 = 7;
```

I have say, 100 variables like this. I want to compare these variables and show an error if any two or more than two variables have similar values. I don't want to do it the long way like this:

```
if((a1 == a2) || (a1 == a3) || ... || (a1 == a100))
{
  //do something
}
if((a2 == a1) || (a2 == a3) || ... || (a2 == a100))
{
  //do something
}
```

Please suggest a shorter method.

P.S: Variables contain only integer values.

Comment: Anything you suggest :)

Comment: Did you define all these 100 variableS? :O

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what arrays are for.

```
var a = new Array();
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 5;
a[3] = 2

var found = false;
for(i = 0;a.length > i;++i)
{
  for(j = i+1; j < a.length;++i)
  {
    if(a[i] != a[j])
    {
      found = true;
      //do something
    }
  }
}
if(!found)
{
  // no dupes, do something else.
}
```

Without arrays:

```
var a1 = 1; 
...

var a100 = 30;

var found = false;
for(i = 1;100 >= i; ++i)
{
  for(j = i+1;100 >= j;++j)
  {
    if( eval('a' + i + ' != a' + j) ) //yuck, but it should work.
    {
      found = true;
      // do something.
    }
  }
}
if(!found)
{
  //no dupes. do something else.
}
```

Comment: You could likely improve performance by sorting the array in O(log(n)) time, and then comparing each item to the item next to it in O(n) time.  I doubt that for small sets (on order of 100 or 200) the difference would matter, but  if we're talking thousands you may want to consider it.

Answer (score -1):

With regex

```
if (/^(something|nothing|anything|everything)$/.exec('jesus')) alert('Who cares?');​
```

Or the opposite:

```
/^(something|nothing|anything|everything)$/.exec('jesus')||alert('Who cares?');
```

[Update] Even shorter ;-)

```
if (/^(some|no|any|every)thing$/.exec('jesus')) alert('Who cares?');​
```

Comment: you can give integer values,or anything whatever you desired

Comment: how to give integer values in it.show an example for it.